# How to use luacrypto?

Tags: lua, openssl

I am trying to use mkottman/luacrypto with Xcode. I added lcrypto.c into my project and compiled it. It was success. Now I created simple .lua file with simple code:

```
crypto = require 'crypto'
assert(crypto.hex, "missing crypto.hex")
```

When I run, I get the error `"module 'crypto' not found:"`.

Could anybody help? What I missed?

Comment: I need to link it statically into my code. How to use luacrypton in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Lua cannot find the library. You should see an error with the locations where it searches for the file. For instance:

```
[string "REPL"]:1: module 'crypto' not found:No LuaRocks module found for crypto
        no field package.preload['crypto']
        no file '/home/phil/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/crypto.lua'
        no file '/home/phil/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/crypto/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/crypto.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/crypto/init.lua'
        no file './crypto.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/crypto.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/crypto/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/crypto.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/crypto/init.lua'
        no file '/home/phil/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/crypto.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/crypto.so'
        no file './crypto.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/crypto.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/crypto.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/repl/init.lua:73: in function </usr/local/share/lua/5.1/repl/init.lua:72>
        (tail call): ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        [string "REPL"]:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/repl/init.lua:101: in function 'old_value'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/repl/init.lua:250: in function 'handleline'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/repl/sync.lua:33: in function 'run'
        ...r/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/luarepl/0.8-1/bin/rep.lua:41: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

As an alternative, you could install it via the package manager [luarocks](https://luarocks.org):

```
$ luarocks search luacrypto

Search results:
===============


Rockspecs and source rocks:
---------------------------

luacrypto
   0.3.2-2 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
   0.3.2-2 (src) - https://luarocks.org
   0.3.2-1 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
   0.3.2-1 (src) - https://luarocks.org
   0.3.0.20120524-1 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
   0.3.0.20120524-1 (src) - https://luarocks.org
   0.2.0-2 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
   0.2.0-2 (src) - https://luarocks.org
   0.2.0-1 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
   0.2.0-1 (src) - https://luarocks.org

luacryptor
   1.0-1 (rockspec) - https://luarocks.org
```

And install it with `luarocks install luacrypto`.

Comment: Philipp, thank you for the answer. I want to link it statically. I expected that I could call "luaopen_crypto(L)" inside my objective c code and then run lua script that uses luacrypto. How can I do this? Regards, Valery.

Answer (score 0):

Philipp is right about missing module. If I add crypto.so into search path, the lua code `require "crypto"` works.
But I need to link luacrypto statically into my c++ project.
I found the following solution.

```
//file.cpp:
luaopen_crypto(L);
lua_setglobal(L, "crypto");

-- file.lua:
--crypto = require "crypto"
print(crypto.hex("123"))
```

This is just a workaround. I set `crypto` as global variable and I can use it in .lua file. But any try to call `local crypto = require "crypto"` will fail.